# A web page application that allows the user to enter one or more stock ticker symbols and display price information about the stocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm trying to create a web page application that allows the user to enter one or more stock ticker symbols and display price information about these stocks.

I am collecting Data from a REST API (https://www.alphavantage.co). I'm using the demo URL.

When symbol is being typed, it says undefined. I'm new to JSON and fetching data, and I need help with this .

Here is my HTML (with Bootsrap) and JQuery

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Stocks</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/simplex/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      </head>


    <body>



      <div class="container">

        <div class="searchContainer">
          <h1>Enter symbol</h1>
          <p class="lead">Enter a a symbol to fetch a price </p>
          <input type="text" id="searchstock" class="form-control" placeholder="Stock symbol...">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="stock"></div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>

   <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#searchstock').on('keyup', function(e){
        let stockSymbol = e.target.value;

        // Make request to rest API
        $.ajax({

          url:'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=MSFT,FB,AAPL&apikey=demo'


          }).done(function(BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES){
            $('#stock').html(`
            ${BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES.price}`
    );
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you placed object literal into html document directly.

When you fetched data from API you got a specific format of data, you need to extract the a piece of data you want from it.

Try this code:

```
// Make request to rest API
    $.ajax({

      url:'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=MSFT,FB,AAPL&apikey=demo'


      }).done(function(BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES){
        let symbol = BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES['Stock Quotes'][0]['1. symbol'];
        let price = BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES['Stock Quotes'][0]['2. price'];
        let timeStamp = BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES['Stock Quotes'][0]['4. timestamp'];
        $('#stock').html(`${symbol} ${price} ${timeStamp}`);
    });
```

You'll get:

> MSFT 93.0300 2018-03-02 15:59:59

This is the [format data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKIz1.png) that I got from using your code

You can find the response format by using tool such as Chrome dev tool.

**Updated**:

In order to use other symbols just extract it with corresponding order with the data.

Ex. FB symbol use

```
let symbol = BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES['Stock Quotes'][1]['1. symbol'];
let price = BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES['Stock Quotes'][1]['2. price'];
let timeStamp = BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES['Stock Quotes'][1]['4. timestamp'];
```

And for getting a response based on user input you have to request by interpolation a value that you got from the input tag as a symbols parameter in the request.

Ex.

```
url:'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=' + e.target.value + '&apikey=demo';
```

Comment: Thanks, how about for the other symbols? this only works with MSFT. even when user enters any letter, it gives the same output. how can you make the output specifically for the symbol that the user input?

Comment: thanks, but now it is saying "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: @jamesbond You should check it yourself. it's just you execute method on undefined variable.